# python NLP and regex missing white space between words

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, whitespace, python-re

I'm trying to process a large text file using NLTK and regular expression. After a few codes, I found that I have missing space between some words. Below are my codes and examples of those words clustered together because of the missing white space. I'd really appreciate it if you could help me see which part of the re code is causing the problem.

The data I started with is:

news
99¢ Only Stores_6-9-2008 99¢ Only Stores(r) Issues Precautionary Recall...
APP Pharmaceuticals_3-26-2011 APP Pharmaceuticals Issues a Nationwide Volunt...
Abbott Diabetes Care_12-22-2010 Abbott Diabetes Care Announces Recall of Certa...
Abbott Nutrition_1-19-2009 Abbott Nutrition Announces Voluntary Recall of...
Abbott_5-25-2007 Abbott Announces Voluntary Nationwide Recall o...

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('max_colwidth',50)

data_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_combined).transpose()
data_df.columns = ['news']
data_df = data_df.sort_index()

def clean_text_round1 (text):

    text=text.split()
    re_punc = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation))
    text = [re_punc.sub('', w) for w in text]
    text = [word for word in text if word.isalpha()]  
    #lem = WordNetLemmatizer()
    #text = [lem.lemmatize(word) for word in text]
    porter = PorterStemmer()
    text = [porter.stem(word) for word in text]
    text = [word for word in text if len(word) > 3]

    return text

round1 = lambda x: clean_text_round1(x)

data_clean = pd.DataFrame(data_df.news.apply(round1))


def clean_text_round2(data_clean):

    data_clean = re.sub('^[A-Z]\w*', '', data_clean)
    data_clean = re.sub('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation), '', data_clean)
    data_clean = re.sub('[‘’“”…]', '', data_clean)
    data_clean = re.sub('(\n|¢)', '', data_clean)
    data_clean = re.sub('\[.*?\]', '', data_clean)    
    data_clean = re.sub('\w*\d\w*', '', data_clean)
    data_clean = data_clean.lower().strip()    
    return data_clean

round2 = lambda x: clean_text_round2(x)

data_clean = pd.DataFrame(data_df.news.apply(round2))
```

Some examples of the wrong output:

abbottabbott, abbottdocument, alexandraspmcommunicationscom, americacustomers

Comment: Did you use both `clean_text_roun1()` and `clean_text_roun2()`? Or just one of them?

Comment: I used both. Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how did you use both? I mean `clean_text_round1()` returns a list not a string. So, in what way did you use both?

Comment: Please edit your question to show all relevant information. This helps future users as well.

Comment: I just edited the code. I hope this is clearer. Thank you both for your response. Could you please help again?

Comment: Could you also show a sample of `data_df.news`?

Comment: Also, could you show us how you read that data sample as a Pandas Dataframe?

Comment: Further, from the code that you have shown us, I don't see effects of `clean_text_round1` being propagated to `clean_text_round_2` since you don't use `data_clean` output from `clean_text_round1`.

Comment: That's a good catch! Thanks. I just corrected the code and used data_clean for the second round. The problem is still there.

Comment: Also, update your question with what you find.